# Changing navigation bar color in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am using a Picker View to allow the user to choose the colour theme for the entire app.

I am planning on changing the colour of the navigation bar, background and possibly the tab bar (if that is possible).

I've been researching how to do this but can't find any Swift examples. Could anyone please give me an example of the code I would need to use to change the navigation bar colour and navigation bar text colour?

The Picker View is set up, I'm just looking for the code to change the UI colours.

Answer (score 634, accepted):

Navigation Bar:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green
```

Replace greenColor with whatever UIColor you want, you can use an RGB too if you prefer.

Navigation Bar Text:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.orange]
```

Replace orangeColor with whatever color you like.

Tab Bar:

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.brown
```

Tab Bar Text:

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.yellow
```

On the last two, replace brownColor and yellowColor with the color of your choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't far off with what I was trying but I didn't quite have things in the right order.

Comment: I'm not sure. If you're using a push segue as opposed to a modal, it should be the same navigation bar, but I'm not completely sure.  Sorry.

Comment: After updating to the newer Xcode betas, setting the title text colour no longer works. titleTextAttributes is not available in Swift. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you open a new question and perhaps link to it?  The chat isn't the best place for something like this.

Comment: No problem. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097980/setting-the-navigation-and-status-bar-text-colour

Comment: I found that its making me use NSForegroundColorAttributeName as the attribute name, but otherwise working great.

Comment: What about NSForegroundColorAttributeName?

Comment: Is it possible to change the navigation bar color with a button on the same view? I tried but it does not seem possible

Comment: New way:     navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]

Comment: I tried this with RGB and it does not work no matter where I put it.

Comment: UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]

Comment: `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` is now `NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor`

Comment: This is not worked for large titles `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`. The color is not changed.

Answer (score 114):

Here are some very basic appearance customization that you can apply app wide:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
//Since iOS 7.0 UITextAttributeTextColor was replaced by NSForegroundColorAttributeName
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [UITextAttributeTextColor: UIColor.blueColor()]
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor();
```

Swift 5.4.2:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .green // backgorund color with gradient
// or
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .green  // solid color
    
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = .magenta
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.blue]
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .yellow
```

More about `UIAppearance` API in Swift you can read [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance).

Comment: So how would I use this to change the colour of the navigation bar for the entire app? At the moment I just have:

self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.newBlueColor()

and of course this just changes the colour of the navigation bar of the view controller that the code is within. How can I use it to change all navigation bars? I tried using: 

UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.newBlueColor()

but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: To reflect chnages in the entier app , paste the above in below method of AppDelegate.swift                                                                                                              func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {  //Place above code                                                                                                                        }

Comment: Use barTintColor instead of backgroundColor. UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()

Comment: @Keenle I am a bit confused... Why does't changing the background color of the UINavigationBar through the appearance API change its color entirely? I tried to set the background color to blue and it gave me a weird shade of purplish blue...

Answer (score 73):

**Updated for Swift 3, 4, 4.2, 5+**

```
// setup navBar.....
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

**Swift 4**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

**Swift 4.2, 5+**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

if you want to work with large title, add this line:

```
UINavigationBar.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Also can check here : https://github.com/hasnine/iOSUtilitiesSource

Comment: Swift 4.2: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor

Comment: setting tint color to white rather than bartintcolor shows the original color. Great!

Comment: @NickCoder appreciate it. :) also check my lib: https://github.com/hasnine/iOSUtilitiesSource

Comment: I can not change my vote! Horrible! Above answer not working for me. I regret that I voted positively but I cannot cancel my vote. This other answer working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795035/bartintcolor-not-applied-when-navigationbar-is-large-titles

Comment: @Markus what's your issue! Why you voted and after that you are trying to down vote! Ask us, we will find a solution for you bro :)

Comment: I downvoted because the solution not worked for me. I simply wanted to remove my previous positive vote. Time ago it was possible, in Stackoverflow.com. Now, no. Pity!

Comment: @Markus ohho sad! try again brother.

Comment: This is not worked after put large title on it `UINavigationBar.appearance().prefersLargeTitles = true`, may I know how to fix it?

Comment: @ChuckZHB It's should work! Please check this apple link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar

Comment: @Jamil Hasnine Tamim, I put an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65667081/10158398 about how to use it in `large title` mode.

Comment: @ChuckZHB nice! and same code I think. And I added large title code in my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 52):

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 46.0/255.0, green: 14.0/255.0, blue: 74.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Just paste this line in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in your code.

Comment: I tried this with RGB and it does not work no matter where I put it.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle Check your RGB, it should in "xx/250.0f" formate.

Comment: Used in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and worked perfectly. Inside viewDidLoad don't work perfectly.

Answer (score 28):

Within **AppDelegate**, this has globally changed the format of the NavBar and removes the bottom line/border (which is a problem area for most people) to give you what I think you and others are looking for:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarPosition: UIBarPosition.Any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Style.SELECTED_COLOR
    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = Style.SELECTED_COLOR
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : (UIFont(name: "FONT NAME", size: 18))!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()] }
```

Then you can setup a **Constants.swift** file, and contained is a Style struct with colors and fonts etc. You can then add a tableView/pickerView to any ViewController and use "availableThemes" array to allow user to change themeColor.

The beautiful thing about this is you can use one reference throughout your whole app for each colour and it'll update based on the user's selected "Theme" and without one it defaults to theme1():

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct Style {


static let availableThemes = ["Theme 1","Theme 2","Theme 3"]

static func loadTheme(){
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let name = defaults.stringForKey("Theme"){
        // Select the Theme
        if name == availableThemes[0]   { theme1()  }
        if name == availableThemes[1]   { theme2()  }
        if name == availableThemes[2]   { theme3()  }
    }else{
        defaults.setObject(availableThemes[0], forKey: "Theme")
        theme1()
    }
}

 // Colors specific to theme - can include multiple colours here for each one
static func theme1(){
   static var SELECTED_COLOR = UIColor(red:70/255, green: 38/255, blue: 92/255, alpha: 1) }

static func theme2(){
    static var SELECTED_COLOR = UIColor(red:255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1) }

static func theme3(){
    static var SELECTED_COLOR = UIColor(red:90/255, green: 50/255, blue: 120/255, alpha: 1) } ...
```

Comment: Thanks man, your answer really helped me
at least for me i used the first part of it and it was awesome and very useful

Comment: Thank you so much man, I tried every answer here and none of them worked except yours :D

Answer (score 23):

**To do this on storyboard (Interface Builder Inspector)**

With help of `IBDesignable`, we can add more options to Interface Builder Inspector for `UINavigationController` and tweak them on storyboard. First, add the following code to your project.

```
@IBDesignable extension UINavigationController {
    @IBInspectable var barTintColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            guard let uiColor = newValue else { return }
            navigationBar.barTintColor = uiColor
        }
        get {
            guard let color = navigationBar.barTintColor else { return nil }
            return color
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply set the attributes for navigation controller on storyboard.

[image]

This approach may also be used to manage the color of the navigation bar text from the storyboard:

```
@IBInspectable var barTextColor: UIColor? {
  set {
    guard let uiColor = newValue else {return}
    navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: uiColor]
  }
  get {
    guard let textAttributes = navigationBar.titleTextAttributes else { return nil }
    return textAttributes[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor] as? UIColor
  }
}
```

Comment: Love it. While I don't think this would work for OP it is an excellent solution for visitors from Google (like me).

Answer (score 22):

**Swift 4:**

**Perfectly working code to change the navigation bar appearance at application level.**

[image]

```
// MARK: Navigation Bar Customisation

// To change background colour.
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .init(red: 23.0/255, green: 197.0/255, blue: 157.0/255, alpha: 1.0)

// To change colour of tappable items.
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white

// To apply textAttributes to title i.e. colour, font etc.
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
                                                    .font : UIFont.init(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 22.0)!]
// To control navigation bar's translucency.
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 18):

Below Codes are working for iOS 15

```
if #available(iOS 15, *) {
        // Navigation Bar background color
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourColor
        
        // setup title font color
        let titleAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: .bold), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.yourColor]
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = titleAttribute
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
```

Comment: this should have 100 upvotes :) thank you!

Answer (score 17):

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor
```

worked for me

Answer (score 17):

**SWIFT 4 - Smooth transition (best solution):**

If you're moving back from a navigation controller and you have to set a diffrent color on the navigation controller you pushed from you want to use

```
override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = Constants.AppColor
}
```

instead of putting it in the viewWillAppear so the transition is cleaner.

**SWIFT 4.2**

```
override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
}
```

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 5 (iOS 14)**

Full navigation bar customization.

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------
// NAVIGATION BAR CUSTOMIZATION
// -----------------------------------------------------------
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

    navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance

} else {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------
// NAVIGATION BAR SHADOW
// -----------------------------------------------------------
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 15
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
```

Answer (score 11):

In **Swift 4**

You can change the color of navigation bar. Just use this below code snippet in `viewDidLoad()`

**Navigation Bar color**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
```

**Navigation Bar Text Color**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.purple]
```

For **iOS 11 Large Title Navigation Bar**, you need to use `largeTitleTextAttributes` property

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.purple]
```

Answer (score 11):

Swift 5, an easy approach with UINavigationController extension. At the bottom of this answer are **extensions** and **previews**.

First view controller (Home):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    navigationController?.setTintColor(.white)
    navigationController?.backgroundColor(.orange)
}
```

Second view controller (Details):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.transparentNavigationBar()
    navigationController?.setTintColor(.black)
}
```

Extensions for UINavigationController:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func transparentNavigationBar() {
        self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    }

    func setTintColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color]
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = color
    }

    func backgroundColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
        navigationBar.barTintColor = color
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
}
```

Storyboard view:

[image]

Previews:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The `appearance()` function not always work for me. So I prefer to create a NC object and change its attributes.

```swift
var navBarColor = navigationController!.navigationBar
navBarColor.barTintColor =
    UIColor(red:  255/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 100.0/100.0)
navBarColor.titleTextAttributes =
    [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Also if you want to add an image instead of just text, that works as well

```swift
var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 70))
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

var image = UIImage(named: "logo")
imageView.image = image
navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Comment: with that way, I was able to change self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title color. Thank u.

Answer (score 9):

Use the appearance API, and barTintColor color.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

Answer (score 9):

In iOS 15, UIKit has extended the usage of the scrollEdgeAppearance, which by default produces a transparent background, to all navigation bars.
Set scrollEdgeAppearance as below code.

```
if #available(iOS 15, *) {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = < your tint color >
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance
    }
```

Comment: The trick on iOS 15 is the last line of this code. Saved my day!

Answer (score 8):

None of the solutions worked for me so I'm sharing the one that did.

**Swift 5, Xcode 13.4.1**

Put the below inside the viewDidLoad():

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        navigationItem.compactAppearance = appearance
```

**This is the result**

[image]

Remember to set all settings in the inspector to default. In case you need more adjustments search via Developers Documentation "Customizing Your App’s Navigation Bar"

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

This version also **removes the 1px shadow line under the navigation bar**:

**Swift 5**: Put this in your **AppDelegate** didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 4):

**iOS 8 (swift)**

```
let font: UIFont = UIFont(name: "fontName", size: 17)   
let color = UIColor.backColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font,NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color], forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have customized navigation controller, you can use above code snippet.
So in my case, I've used as following code pieces.

**Swift 3.0, XCode 8.1 version**

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green
```

**Navigation Bar Text:**

```
navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.orange]
```

It is very helpful talks.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4, iOS 12 and Xcode 10 Update**

Just put one line inside `viewDidLoad()`

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 4):

**iOs 14+**

```
init() {        
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.shadowColor = .clear // gets also rid of the bottom border of the navigation bar
    appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground() 
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```

Comment: Where do you set color here? It does not really answer the question.

Comment: according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarappearance/3197998-configurewithopaquebackground it's available since iOS 13

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 2

For changing color in navigation bar,

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

For changing color in item navigation bar,

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

or

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor()]
```

Answer (score 3):

### Swift 3

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 51/255, green: 90/255, blue: 149/255, alpha: 1)
```

This will set your navigation bar color like Facebook bar color :)

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

Simple one liner that you can use in `ViewDidLoad()`

```
//Change Color
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
//Change Text Color
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3 and Swift 4 Compatible Xcode 9**

**A Better Solution for this to make a Class for common Navigation bars**

I have 5 Controllers and each controller title is changed to orange color. As each controller has 5 navigation controllers so i had to change every one color either from inspector or from code.

**So i made a class instead of changing every one Navigation bar from code i just assign this class and it worked on all 5 controller Code reuse Ability.**
**You just have to assign this class to Each controller and thats it.**

```
import UIKit

   class NabigationBar: UINavigationBar {
      required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonFeatures()
 }

   func commonFeatures() {

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white;
      UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes =     [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:ColorConstants.orangeTextColor]

 }


  }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using iOS 13 or 14 and large title, and want to change navigation bar color, use following code:

Refer to [barTintColor not applied when NavigationBar is Large Titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795035/bartintcolor-not-applied-when-navigationbar-is-large-titles)

```
    fileprivate func setNavigtionBarItems() {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
            appearance.backgroundColor = .brown
//            let naviFont = UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 30) ?? .systemFont(ofSize: 30)
//            appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: naviFont]
            
            navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
            navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
            //navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .brown
        }
    }
```

This took me 1 hour to figure out what is wrong in my code:(, since I'm using large title, it is hard to change the tintColor with largeTitle, why apple makes it so complicated, so many lines to just make a tintColor of navigationBar.

Answer (score 2):

**iOS 10 Swift 3.0**

If you don't mind to use swift frameworks then us [UINeraida](http://www.appangel.16mb.com/) to change navigation background as `UIColor` or `HexColor` or `UIImage` and change navigation back button text programmatically, change complete forground text color.

**For `UINavigationBar`**

```
    neraida.navigation.background.color.hexColor("54ad00", isTranslucent: false, viewController: self)
    
    //Change navigation title, backbutton colour
    
    neraida.navigation.foreground.color.uiColor(UIColor.white, viewController: self)
    
    //Change navigation back button title programmatically
    
    neraida.navigation.foreground.backButtonTitle("Custom Title", ViewController: self)
    
    //Apply Background Image to the UINavigationBar
    
    neraida.navigation.background.image("background", edge: (0,0,0,0), barMetrics: .default, isTranslucent: false, viewController: self)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .Black
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

otherwise the background color wouldn't change

Answer (score 1):

First set the isTranslucent property of navigationBar to false to get the desired colour. Then change the navigationBar colour like this:

```
@IBOutlet var NavigationBar: UINavigationBar!

NavigationBar.isTranslucent = false
NavigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor (red: 117/255, green: 23/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to set the **Button State for .normal**

```
extension UINavigationBar {

    func makeContent(color: UIColor) {
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? = [.foregroundColor: color]

        self.titleTextAttributes = attributes
        self.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
        self.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

P.S iOS 12, Xcode 10.1

Comment: Thank you. I have been searching for hours for this `topItem` solution. It's frustrating the number of changes Apple continue to make to how styles are applied to the navigation.

Answer (score 1):

> Try This in AppDelegate:

```
//MARK:- ~~~~~~~~~~setupApplicationUIAppearance Method
func setupApplicationUIAppearance() {

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor =  UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: AnyObject]

    if DeviceType.IS_IPAD{
        attributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 30)
            ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : AnyObject]
    }else{
        attributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white
        ]
    }
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributes
}
```

> iOS 13

```
func setupNavigationBar() {
    //        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    //            let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
    //            let statusBar = UIView(frame: window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero)
    //            statusBar.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2784313725, green: 0.4549019608, blue: 0.5921568627, alpha: 1) //UIColor.init(hexString: "#002856")
    //            //statusBar.tintColor = UIColor.init(hexString: "#002856")
    //            window?.addSubview(statusBar)
    //            UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    //            UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    //            UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    //            UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2784313725, green: 0.4549019608, blue: 0.5921568627, alpha: 1)
    //            UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
    //        }
    //        else
    //        {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2784313725, green: 0.4549019608, blue: 0.5921568627, alpha: 1)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2784313725, green: 0.4549019608, blue: 0.5921568627, alpha: 1)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
    //        }
}
```

> Extensions

```
extension UIApplication {

var statusBarView: UIView? {
    if responds(to: Selector(("statusBar"))) {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }
    return nil
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply call the this extension and pass the color it will automatically change the color of nav bar

```
extension UINavigationController {
    
     func setNavigationBarColor(color : UIColor){
            self.navigationBar.barTintColor = color
        }
    }
```

in the view didload or in viewwill appear call

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarColor(color: <#T##UIColor#>)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this for those that still have problems with the solutions here.

I'm using Xcode Version 11.4 (11E146). The one working for me is:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
```

BUT!, if you set the barTintColor in storyboard to any other value than "default" this 2 lines of code will have no effect.

So, be carefull and set back to default barTintColor in Storyboard.
Oh Apple...

Comment: Still same problem despite changing tint colour to default :(

Comment: @marika.daboja All your navigation controllers in storyboard are set to default colors?

Comment: Hi, I only have 1 Navigation Controller (plus 2 Table View Controllers). Navigation Controller Bar Tint colour is set to 'default'. Code I have to update this colour seems to not have an affect on it.

Comment: @marika.daboja make sure you that navigationController is not nil. And that you put this lines of code in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

### ****If you're using iOS 13 to use this methods to change navigation bar color****

**Swift 4 and Swift 5 Compatible Xcode 15+**

```
func navigationThemeSetting(navView: UIViewController) {
        
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .red
            navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : .white]
            navView.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance;
            navView.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance;
        } else {
            navView.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = ex_clrThemeColor
            navView.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : .white]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

My two cents:

a) setting navigationBar.barTintColor / titleTextAttributes do work in any view (pushed, added..and so on in init..

b) setting appearence does not work everywhere:

- You can call it on AppDelegate
- "      "         1st level view
- if You call it again in subsequent pushed views, does MNOT work

SwiftUI note:

a) does not apply (no navigationBar, unless you pass via UIViewControllerRepresentable trick..)
b) is valid for SwiftUI: same behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

I'm working in Xcode 14.1 for iOS 16.1

I had to change the scrollEdgeAppearance to actually change the color of the navBar. The background color was only making a really translucent color even if I had disabled the translucent property.

So it went like this:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = UIColor.*/your_color/*
```

Comment: This isn't valid. The `scrollEdgeAppearance` property needs an instance of `UINavigationBarAppearance`, not `UIColor`.

Comment: it did work though. I was using chameleon framework, could it be why it worked?