# Setting the Navigation and Status Bar text colour

Tags: xcode, swift

I am trying to change the text colour of the navigation bar in my app, however I can't figure out how it's done. Prior to Xcode 6 beta 2 I was using:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [UITextAttributeTextColor: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

And that worked absolutely fine but after updating to the newer versions I just get an error stating that 'titleTextAttributes' is not available in Swift.

Also, how can I change the text colour of the status bar? I've tried changing it in the Attributes inspector and I have also tried doing it via code by following Objective C examples, but I still cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UITextAttributeTextColor` is deprecated; you need to use `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in regards to changing the status bar style. Here is the tutorial that I followed:

http://codebleep.com/setting-the-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7/

Comment: Link not working any more. Would you paste the tutorial here? (then I would upvote this answer!).