# How to change background color of UINavigationItem?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationitem

I have a `UINavigationItem`, but I can't found anything beside tittle, prompt, and back button in attribute inspector

[image]

I wonder how can I change my `UINavigationItem` background color using code? or programmatically?

Comment: Possibly Crop that image a bit ?

Comment: U can change the image background or u can add it programmatically and make the the icon has a transparent background.

Comment: @bumble_bee_ tuna I want to show that there is nothing except that 3 option in attribute inspector :)

Comment: @bejibun how can i do that in code using swift?

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra I suppose but 75% of it is unnecessary and it makes your question difficult to read.

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra I have posted answer please try it and inform me.

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra i have up voted for your question can you do same for my answer.

Comment: You don't see any settings because you are looking at a top bar added via the Simulated Metrics. Super confusing. This is just a place holder for the top bar.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can change it through code...

**For Objective-C:**

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Write Above line in viewDidLoad method.

**For Swift:**

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor  = UIColor.redColor();
```

OR

```
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar .setBackgroundImage(UIImage .new(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage .new();
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = true;
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
```

You can change color on your own choice.

**To change the bar Text...**

```
navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [UITextAttributeTextColor: UIColor.blueColor()]
```

See the Link.... 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687238/changing-navigation-bar-color-in-swift)

[image]

See the above image... you like output like this screen right...!!!

Comment: you want to change background color of Navigation bar right?

Comment: nope, I want to change background color of uinavigationitem

Comment: mean you want to change the back button color.. background color

Comment: no, it almost the same with uinavigationbar but it doesn't have anything on attribute inspector except that 3 things

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra i have edited my answer please try it again because it works for me.i have posted updated answer please try it.

Comment: what I want to change is not uinavigationbar :D

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra Actually this is the code to change navigation item background. you first try it.

Comment: it does work for me, I'm using barTintColor instead of backgroundcolor :D thank you

Comment: UINavigationBar is a special view, you shouldn't access the backgroundColor property.

Comment: I've no doubt that this works in some case, but there a different between "works" and "you should use this".

Comment: What you are saying is ridiculous, I downvoted your answer because is not the most accurate.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the background property of UINavigationBar, but instead you should use barTintColor like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

As written in the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/barTintColor) to change the bar background you have to access to the barTintColor property:

```
The tint color to apply to the navigation bar background.
```

If you want to edit the style of the navigation bar such as button color you should access to the barTint property. If you want to edit the style of an navigationItem such as back button you should edit the button property, not the UINavigationItem's.

Comment: You should learn to read the official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/barTintColor

"The tint color to apply to the navigation bar background."

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to embed the View Controller it is containing the Navigation Item in a Navigation Controller and access to properties color of Navigation Bar:

```
// Color title 'navigationItem'
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]

// Background 'navigationBar'
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

// Color title 'navigationBar'
let color = UIColor.orangeColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(
    [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color], forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 4

```
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false;
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white
```