# How to change the theme and colour of Xcode navigator area?

Tags: xcode, colors, themes

Although I can change the theme and colour of Xcode text edit area, I cant't find how to change Xcode navigator area? Hope to get a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing navigation bar color in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687238/changing-navigation-bar-color-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so it is possible.
I havn't came through any such customisation for xcode, though you can change font and color or editor area and console.