# UINavigationBar - change title color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I try to change the color of the navigationBar title and tried the following:

```
let navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = UIColor.red
navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Everything works fine but the color of the title is not changing. It is still black. I thought this line will change it

```
navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
```

Is this wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687238/changing-navigation-bar-color-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your controller, you have to set the color once for large and normal title.

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red]
```