# barTintColor not applied when NavigationBar is Large Titles

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationbarappearance

I'm updating an app that was compiled on Xcode 10 and running fine up through iOS 13. I wanted to make some changes so recompiled on Xcode 11 and now have a problem with the barTintColor.

If 'Large Titles' is set to 'Always' my custom barTintColor is not applied -- I just get the default gray. If 'Large Titles' is set to 'Never', my custom barTintColor is applied as expected. If 'Large Titles' is set to 'Automatic', the NavBar is default gray when Large Titles are shown and my custom color when small titles are shown. For example, when the TableView below my nav bar is pushed up, the default large title switches to small title, and my NavBar changes color. Normal behavior would be for it always to be my custom color.

The relevant code from my ViewController class, with the last line being the one that sets the barTintColor:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setDelegates()
    setTableViewHeightForCollapsingHeaders()
    setNavigtionBarItems()
    doSplitViewManagement()
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = splitViewController!.isCollapsed
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    updateUI()
}

fileprivate func setNavigtionBarItems() {
    //set up UI buttons
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(insertNewObject(_:)))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(hex: 0x5da0a2)

}
```

Any idea why the behavior changed, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a new API since iOS 13 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbarappearance

The backgroundColor property you're looking for is in the super class
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarappearance

Some extra sample code here
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar

Comment: This was what I was looking for -- thanks! There were a few subtleties I had to resolve after trying to implement with the above docs, so I'll answer the question myself, too. Hopefully that's appropriate in terms of acknowledging your contribution.

Answer (score 8):

Apple's documentation that glotcha pointed to was critical to solving the problem although there was a bit more to it. Here's the updated version of my `setNavigationBarItems()` that works in iOS 13:

```
fileprivate func setNavigtionBarItems() {

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = myBackgroundColor

        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        //navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance
        
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = myBackgroundColor
    }
}
```

A key point in my case was that my Navigation Bar is set (in Autolayout) with 'Large Titles' as 'Automatic'. This makes it necessary to include the `.scrollEdgeAppearance` line so that the custom appearance applies when it transitions from large to compact. It turned out the `.compactAppearance` line was not required because I use the same color for both. If I wanted different appearance settings for large and compact then a line with `.compactAppearance` would also be useful.

Comment: Great answer. Hard to find the correct solution. I had the same problem but now, it is solved with your solution. Great job!

Comment: Thanks, I used large title, it seems this is the only correct solution. BTW, do you know how to change the font and size of `largeTitle`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a single place to do it for the whole app:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    let barBackgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 47/255, green: 54/255, blue: 64/255, alpha: 1.0)
    
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = barBackgroundColor
    appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided code is setting up a UINavigationController and customizing the appearance of its UINavigationBar for an iOS 15 application.

```
let nav = UINavigationController()
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = .white
    nav.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
    nav.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = nav.navigationBar.standardAppearance
```

Regarding the **navBarTintColor**, it's important to note that starting from iOS 13, Apple introduced a new way to customize the navigation bar using UINavigationBarAppearance. In `iOS 15`, this approach is still valid, and setting the backgroundColor as done in the code should work for achieving a white background color. If you want to set the **tint color** specifically, you can use **appearance.backgroundColor** or **nav.navigationBar.tintColor** depending on your needs.