# My navigation bar doesn't go to the top of the screen in Xcode 13.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios15, xcode13

I am using a navigation controller and my navigation bar will not extend to the top of the screen. I never had an issue with this until I updated Xcode to version 13.0. I am using storyboard and can't figure out why this issue is happening. (See photo)

[image: screenshot of storyboard]

Comment: please share some code. Including your constraints.

Comment: I am not using any code or constraints. I just dragged a navigation controller onto the storyboard and this is what it looks like.

Comment: Ahh its a navigation controller. Makes sense. I don't use storyboards. I'm not even sure you can do this on storyboards. Here is how you would do it programatically. Look at the examples using `UINavigationBar.appearance()` if you wanna change it everywhere in the app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687238/changing-navigation-bar-color-in-swift?rq=1. Just place the code in your `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function. Edit: Oh you can set it on storyboards, just enable "Scroll Edge" and set the background of Scroll Edge

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for how to make it with storyboards, simply turn on "Scroll Edge" in the attributes inspector, while you tap on the Navigation bar...[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oibeO.png)

If you are not using storyboards, try setting a delegate object for the navigation bar.

```
navigationBar.delegate = self
```

Conform UIBarPositioningDelegate in your delegate object and attach bar to the top

```
ViewController: UIViewController, UIBarPositioningDelegate {
func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
    return .topAttached
}
```